# JQuery - updating a global variable when submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms

First, let me explain what my design look like.

I have a 'home.ejs' file linking with a 'data.js' file, when the form inside the 'home.ejs' sent post request to Nodejs server, the server will render a "timer.ejs" file to client, the 'timer.ejs' is linking to the 'data.js' and 'test.js' file.

```
|-index.js
  |--public
     |--data.js
     |--test.js
  |--views
     |--home.ejs
     |--timers.ejs
```

What I want to achieve is, inside the 'data.js' of 'home.ejs', when the form in 'home.ejs' submitting, it will update the global variable 'logicArr' and pass to the 'test.js' file. So when Nodejs render 'timer.ejs' to client, the new value of variable 'logicArr' will pass to 'test.js' file since both js file are under 'timer.ejs'.

However, inside the 'test.js' of 'timer.ejs', the 'logicArr' is still [1,2,3], which means it has not updated and pass to 'test.js'.

So are there any ways to update the global variable 'logicArr' when submit the form?

```
//data.js

let formData;
let logicArr = [1,2,3];

$("#myForm").on("submit", (e) => {

  formData = $("form").serializeArray();

  console.log("formData is below");

  logicArr = createLogic(formData);

});
```

In the "timer.ejs", I link to 'data.js' and 'test.js'

```
//timer.ejs

<script src="/data.js"></script>
<script src="/test.js">
   console.log(logicArr);
</script>
```

Comment: use var as it has global scope

Comment: Variables don't persist between different web pages. Use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Comment: also it can be work also if you create function and call it and pass with parameter

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for your suggestion, so for the same client, the localStorage is the same for different web pages?

Comment: As long as they're in the same domain.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks so much! Seems using sessionStorage has solved my problem! Thanks!